# Getting an error even when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

From all the examples I found, using `is(':checked')` should return true if checkbox is checked, and false if not. In my case it returns false on both situations. What is my mistake?

```
          {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            boxLabel: 'Show message',
            id: 'mainBox',
            handler: function() {
                alert($(this).is(':checked'));

          }
```

Comment: What does this code generate ? an `<input>` or anything else ? The question is, What's `this` ?

Comment: It seems you're missing an ending brace to the handler function. and what does $(this) refer to? Please provide your entire code so that we can see what you're trying to accomplish. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In accordance to the **[ExtJS documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Checkbox)**, I would try this:

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    boxLabel: 'Show message',
    id: 'mainBox',
    handler: function (field , value) {
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `this` inside a extjs event handler does not refer to the dom element instead `this` will refer to a extjs checkbox object. jQuery won't be able to find out the target element using the extjs object reference. Instead you have the [getValue()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Checkbox-method-getValue) method of checkbox which will return the checked state value, so

Try

```
{
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    boxLabel: 'Show message',
    id: 'mainBox',
    handler: function (el) {
        alert(el.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the jQuery documentation, the [.is('...')](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function returns an jQuery object.

If you want some kind of a **boolean as return value**, you can try the following code:

```
alert($(this).is(':checked').length > 0);
```

But for a checkbox element, using the **'checked' property** should work too:

```
alert(this.checked);
```

You can even try this if you want to use jQuery:

```
alert($(this).attr('checked') === 'checked');
```